# Sequelize - Combine two boolean attributes into one alias

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Currently working in Sequelize with MySql and trying to generate a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT (isActive AND isValid) as isWorking FROM users;
```

That's a simplified example, my query has a bunch of joins and other attributes and I need to use the `Sequelize.col()` method to get it to work. So like this:

```
models.User.findAll({
  attributes: [ 
    [Sequelize.col('User.isActive'), 'isWorking']
  ]
});
```

Is there a way to get that `AND` combination in the attributes list?

Comment: try sequelize.literal

Comment: I can't because of the need for `Sequelize.col`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a workaround doing

```
[Sequelize.fn('LEAST', Sequelize.col('User.isActive'), Sequelize.col('User.isValid)), 'isWorking']
```